# Java is not installed issue on Mac

Tags: java, java-11, magic-draw

I am trying to install Magic Draw Enterprise, and it requires Java 11.0.9. I installed it and in my terminal I wrote java -version to check if it was the right one and yes it is.
This is what comes out.

```
java version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

However, when I try to open MagicDraw it says Java is not installed. Please install Java in order to launch MagicDraw. Anyone knows what might be the reason?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps it relies on the `JAVA_HOME` envvar, that may not be set? What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` output?

Comment: In the MagicDraw installation file I had to put the value to the JAVA_HOME envvar as it was left empty. Many thanks!

Comment: If they don't have this step detailed as part of their setup/readme, ask them to add it. Might help others in future.